# Mapping from string into object parameter

Tags: swift, mapping

I have a dictionary with an identifier and a value. For example

```
mappingDictionary["vehicle.fuel_level"] = 50
```

Now I want to transfer the Dictionary into an object. The object is a rather large object with some child objects.

```
class Status {
// ... 
var vehicle: Vehicle? 
// ...
} 

class Vehicle {
//  ...
var fuel_level: Int? 
// ....
}
```

The naive approach would be to simply make an If query

```
if dictionary.key = "vehicle.fuel_level" {
   statusObject.vehicle.fuel_level = dictionary.value
}
```

Is there perhaps a generic solution? Using Reflection, I could at least find out where `"vehicle.fuel_level"` would need to be written. But how do I get a value into an object if you don't know where the value should go?

Is there a kind of "route" to address an object?

Pseudocode:

```
statusObject["vehicle"].[fuel_level] = dictionary.value
```

Update:
The data comes from a bluetooth device. The app reads characteristic values. For example the value is just 0,1 or 2. For every characteristic exist a Mapping.

So a bluetooth connector reads values and returns them to an interactor. The interactor calls an interpreter. The interpreter has a mapping config with a type (for example int8, int16, short) and a unit (for example km, percent ...). And this mapping should fill the destination object. So, it would be very nice, when I could say: Put value from string "vehicle.fuel_level" into object `vehicle.fuel_level = newValue`

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Can you explain your situation further? Where does the dictionary come from initially? Is it JSON?

Comment: Thanks for response. I updated my question. The data comes from a bluetooth device

Comment: Okay, can't you just change the code that fills the dictionary to not fill the dictionary, and instead create an object?

Comment: I updated again my question. Maybe now it is a little bit clearer

Comment: You may consider to conform Codable protocol at each object. See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable